# Where can I read a clear explanation of POE (Perl Object Environment)?

Tags: perl, poe

I am searching for about a week for a good and clear tutorial for POE that is relevant to 2010 and didn't find one.

I found some tutorials in the Stack Overflow question [*Where can I find books or tutorials for Perl’s POE?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948397/where-can-i-find-books-or-tutorials-for-perls-poe) under the [`poe` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/poe) but most of the materials are old and not clear.

Could someone provide a clear link/lecture/tutorials about POE if there are any? If not, it would be awesome if someone writes POE tutorials for beginners and advanced users; it could help the Perl community a lot.

Comment: "Clear" is very subjective. Just say which part of the existing documentation you have problems with, that can be fixed more easily than writing something new.

Comment: Hi daxim the tutorials i saw are old and the most updated tutorial goes back to 2004,and there are many poe components on cpan
i even didn't know which component is the best to use for specific task also i can't find a tutorial discuss how can someone build a specific component if he need to do that.I think if there are 3 poe tutorials written one for the beginner the second for itermediate and the third for advanced this could contribute much to the perl community.even if published a book on this subject it could be less headache for many people and great resource for the perl community

Answer (score 4):

I must admit that this question does make sense. I find POE very powerful but not having the documentation it deserves.

If I was you I'd rather start with the main documentation on CPAN: http://search.cpan.org/dist/POE/lib/POE.pm

then I'll give it a try to one of this examples in POE Cookbook:
http://poe.perl.org/?POE_Cookbook

IMO it would be great to have for POE the same kind of core documentation available for example for python Twisted.

Answer (score 2):

At the risk of sounding naive, there seem to be some useful tidbits at POE website itself:

http://poe.perl.org/?POE_Documentation

There is [an intro](http://poe.perl.org/?What_POE_Is), [tutorials](http://poe.perl.org/?Tutorials) (though admittedly a bit dated), a cookbook and a beginner/advanced guides.